# angular js ng-repeat a radio button list from scope with a default checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
app.controller('radiusController', function($scope){
    $scope.radii = [
        {id:.25, checked:"false", name:"1/4 Mile"},
        {id:.5, checked:"false", name:"1/2 Mile"},
        {id:1, checked:"false", name:"1 Mile"},
        {id:2, checked:"true", name:"2 Mile"},
        {id:3, checked:"false", name:"3 Mile"},
        {id:4, checked:"false", name:"4 Mile"},
        {id:5, checked:"false", name:"5 Mile"}
    ];
    $scope.handleRadioClick = function(radius){
        window.radiochecked = radius.id;
    };
});

<li ng-repeat="radius in radii" id="selectradius-{{radius.id}}">

              <div class="radio">
                <label>

                  <input type="radio" name="radius"
                       ng-model="radius.checked"
                       ng-change="handleRadioClick(radius)">

                  {{radius.name}}

                </label>
              </div>

          </li>
```

How do I set the default radio button to be checked based on the checked value of scope radii? In this case the "2 Mile" should be checked by default.

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RP9SpO1qGjn5Ua6pZJ3D?p=preview

Comment: set the value to ng-model variable so `$scope.radius.checked = $scope.radii[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple. Eventhough the angular docs do not mention ng-checked, it is available.

```
<input type="radio" name="radius"
                       ng-change="handleRadioClick(radius)"
                       ng-checked="radius.checked">
```

Comment: get `Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!`

Answer (score 0):

you can set the ng-model to the specified value you want in controller

```
$scope.radius.checked = $scope.radii[0]
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. ng-model is currently set to invoke the ng-change function.

Comment: hgrathi, that didn't work. setting ng-model to a scope value does just that but not check the radio button.

Comment: Still haven't found a way to do this. Anyone else? See code above.

Comment: can you add the code in plunker. i would try to fix from there

Answer (score 0):

Create an object to hold the selected value, like:

$scope.selectedValue = {
        id: 0
      };

Update ng-model and value attributes like shown below:

```
 <input type="radio" name="radius" ng-change="handleRadioClick()" 
          ng-model="selectedValue.id" value="{{radius.id}}">
```

See working sample:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zpNItMx13YPH0guvod0D?p=preview

Comment: It does not work. Just first click on each radio calls `ngChange`

Answer (score 0):

All simple here

`ngModel` holds a model(where we want store selected item)
`ngValue` holds a value(what item related to this input)

To access `scope` which we want, we should step up from `ngRepeat` scope with `$parent`.

```
<div ng-repeat="radius in radii">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radius"
             ng-model="$parent.model"
             ng-value="radius" />
        {{radius.name}}
      </label>
</div>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7kxHp67r8gs7X8O1SUt?p=preview)