# Angular: How to use ngRepeat and set a default radio button option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551708/angularjs-ngrepeat-and-default-checked-radio-button), but it wasn't very helpful because they're using ng-repeat differently.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389701/angular-js-ng-repeat-a-radio-button-list-from-scope-with-a-default-checked) is also not helpful.

I have a form:

```
<label ng-repeat="option in options">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="myObject.value" ng-value="option.key">
</label>
```

My angular controller:

```
options = {
  key: 'Option 1'
  val: 'Value 1'
}
$scope.myObject = { value: 'default option' }
```

I would like this to set a default radio option. What's happening is that the last `option in list` is set as the default no matter what I try. I'm sure I don't understand why that is, so here I am.

How do I set a default radio option and what's wrong with my current configuration? Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular js ng-repeat a radio button list from scope with a default checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389701/angular-js-ng-repeat-a-radio-button-list-from-scope-with-a-default-checked)

Comment: @MarkoGrešak Thanks but I don't know what's going on in that example either and that solution isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value of `myObject.value` as the default option of the input, there must be an option with that key.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2cb53pj3/

Just set `$scope.myObject.value` with a matching value of the keys of your `options` array

Comment: This example seems to indicate what you say isn't entirely true: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D That example shows options coming from 3 different places. Maybe you can better explain what you're saying?

Comment: @Proto In the example of the link the input has a binding with `$scope.color.name` and the value of that variable is **blue**. As a result, the default selected input is the one with **blue** value. In your example, your input has a binding with `$scope.myObject.value`. As a result, the default selected input will be the one that matches `$scope.myObject.value` value. Furthermore, your input is populated with an `option.key` array so that is the reason of the statement "If you want to set the value of `myObject.value` as the default option of the input, there must be an option with that key."

Answer (score 0):

Had this ready, but the other answer was submitted before mine.  You need to set `myObject.value` to match the `option.key` you want to be the default.

Script.js

```
(function () {
angular.module('radioExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

      $scope.options = [{
        'key': 'Option 1',
        'val': 'Value 1'
      }, {
        'key': 'Option 2',
        'val': 'Value 2'
      }, {
        'key': 'Option 3',
        'val': 'Value 3'
      }];

      $scope.myObject = {
        value: 'Option 2'
      };
    }
  ]);
})();
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="radioExample">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="Options">
    <div ng-repeat="option in options">
      <label>{{option.key}}</label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="myObject.value" ng-value="option.key">

    </div>
    Selected option is {{myObject.value}}
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You also should have your data formatted as an array instead of an object in order for AngularJS to iterate through it.